# Trying to exclude unwanted GROUP BY categories in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I am able to run the following query just fine, except the results are returning empty rows for 'Archived' and 'Rejected' (which are the other two status's in the status column) which I wish to exclude from the results

```
SELECT status,
sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY status
```

Right now the query returns:

```
0             1   2   3
Archived      0   0   0
Rejected      0   0   0
New           5   0   0
Active        0   4   0
Closed        0   0   7
```

I am trying to get it to return:

```
0             1   2   3
New           5   0   0
Active        0   4   0
Closed        0   0   7
```

Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: i thought maybe, just maybe you want to have simply 5,4,7 returned as 1 row of result instead since you're already coding 'New','Active','Closed' so you know which is which already

Comment: something like this maybe [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56189/3/0), maybe not I don't know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add : `HAVING status NOT IN('Archieved', 'Rejected')` after GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try excluding them literally from your select;

```
SELECT status,
sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Contact
WHERE Status <> 'Archived'
AND   Status <> 'Rejected'
GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add having clause

```
SELECT status,
sum(case when status = 'New' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end),
sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Contact
GROUP BY status
Having status NOT IN('Archieved', 'Rejected');
```

For better understanding about it just see the use of [Having](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29)

Comment: That was very helpful. I appreciate the instruction. Thx